# How do I find how much memory is taken by a struct?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management

Simple question: Is there a way how to find out how much memory is taken by particular struct?

Ideally I would like it printed to console.

---

**Edit:** Krumelur came with simple solution using `sizeof` function.

Unfortunatelly it does not seems to work well with arrays. Following code

```
println("Size of int \(123) is: \(sizeofValue(123))")
println("Size of array \([0]) is: \(sizeofValue([0]))")
println("Size of array \([0, 1, 8, 20]) is: \(sizeofValue([0, 1, 8, 20]))")
```

Produces this output:

```
Size of int 123 is: 8
Size of array [0] is: 8
Size of array [0, 1, 8, 20] is: 8
```

So different sizes of arrays give same size what is surely incorrect (at least for my purpose).

Comment: sizeof(MyStruct) maybe?

Comment: @Krumelur Looks good... why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: Too few chars, I had to be creative :)

Comment: @Krumelur If you want you can add some more chars by telling me what units is return value of `sizeof(MyStruct)`. Or `sizeofValue(myStruct)`. Cannot find either and link to documentation would also help me.

Comment: 8 is the size of a 64 bit address which I assume is what an array variable is in swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof(T)` operator is available in Swift. It returns the size taken up by the specified type or variable, just like in C.

Unlike C, however, there is no concept of a stack-allocated array (static array). An array is a pointer to an object, meaning that its size will always be a size of a pointer (this is the same as for heap-allocated arrays in C). To get the size of an array, you have to do something like

```
array.count * sizeof(Telement)
```

but even that is only true if `Telement` is not an object that allocates heap memory.

Comment: All right, I get it - I will just use `sizeof` on type that is element type of an array, multiply by count of elements in array and that sum results for all arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be supported within the Swift standard library now.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2486283-size)

```
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Declan McKenna pointed out, MemoryLayout.size is now a part of the standard library ("Foundation").

You use this in one of two ways: either you get the size of a *type* via <> bracket syntax, or of a *value* by calling it as a function:

```swift
var someInt: Int
let a = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: someInt)
let b = MemoryLayout<Int>.size
/* a and b are equal */
```

Suppose you have an array `arr` of type `T`, you can get the allocated size as follows:

```swift
let size = arr.capacity * MemoryLayout<T>.size
```

Note that you should use `arr.capacity`, not `arr.count`. Capacity refers to how much memory has been reserved for the array, even if all the values haven't been written to.

Another thing to note is that memory allocations can be a bit tricky. If you allocate a large block of memory and never write to it, the operating system might not report the application as actually *using* that memory. The operating system might let you `malloc` some enormous block of memory that's a thousand times larger than your actual memory, but if you never actually write anything to it, it won't *really* get allocated.

The method described in this answer is for getting the hypothetical maximum amount allocated by the array.